# How to map a matrix to a coordinate and plot it

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I have been struggling with this problem for a while and I would appreciate if anyone can help me out. I am able to generate a 10 by 10 matrix and have it randomly assign "1"s in the matrix. My goal is to plot a "star" at the location of each element in the vector that has a value of "1", but I can't seem to figure out how to map the vector to a x-y coordinate system. The code I wrote below generates a plot of 100 stars at each cell and also generates a vector "v", but I don't know how I can link the plot to the vector that instead of having 100 "star"s in my plot, I have however many that there is a value of "1" at the corresponding location of the element.

Thanks!!
David
davidtongg@gmail.com

```
close all
clear all
clc

a=10;b=10;
v = zeros(a,b);
xy = int32(randi(a, 100, 2));
z = randi(1, 100, 1); % 100 values.

indexes = sub2ind([a, b], xy(:,1), xy(:,2))
v(indexes) = z

m=length(v);
ctr=0;
for i=1:m^2
    x_cor(i)=(i-(floor(i/m)*m))*200-100;
    y_cor(i)=(floor(i/m)+1)*200-100;
    for j=1:m
        if i==j*m
            x_cor(i)=((i-(floor(i/m)*m))*200-100)+(2*m*100);
            y_cor(i)=(floor(i/m))*200-100;
        end
    end

end


figure(1)

plot(x_cor,y_cor,'*');

grid on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily taking into account that `plot(A)` , where `A` is a matrix, plots the columns of the matrix vs their index, and that `NaN`s are not plotted:

```
v =[ 1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     0 ]; %// example data

v2 = double(v); %// create copy; will be overwritten
v2(~v2) = NaN; %// change zeros to NaNs
plot(bsxfun(@plus, fliplr(v2.'), 0:size(v,1)-1) ,'b*')
%'// transpose and flip from left to right.
%//  Add 1 incrementally to each column to have all of them "stacked" in the plot
axis([0 size(v,2)+1 0 size(v,1)+1]) %// set axis limits
set(gca,'xtick',1:size(v,2),'ytick',1:size(v,1)) %// set ticks
grid
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Luis, wow this plot(bsxfun.....) looks so complicated and I have never seen anything like that. could you explain a little bit more on what that does and also what the "set ticks" command does? Another thing I try to figure out is if you look at the code I posted above, in the for loop what I was trying to do is to have a grid of 10 by 10 (or more cells) and each cell has a length of 200 and plot the "star" in the middle of that cell to represent a wind turbine location. Is there anyway to modify your ploting code so it plots in the middle of a 200 x 200 cell for each "star" thanksagain

Answer (score 1):

I may of course have misinterpreted this because that code is confusingly complicated, but this is what I *think* you're after.

For an `a`x`b` matrix with a random number of ones:

```
v = randi([0 1], a, b);
```

Or for a specific number `n` of ones, in random locations:

```
v = zeros(a, b);
idx = randi([1 numel(v)], n, 1);
v(idx) = 1; % linear indexing into a matrix
```

Then to plot them in arbitrarily scaled coordinates:

```
[y x] = find(v);
x = x * xscale + xoffset;
y = y * yscale + yoffset;
plot(x, y, '*');
```

Or the really cheaty way:

```
spy(v);
```

Comment: @Sharkbait is the error by any chance "these variable names that some guy pulled out of the air to illustrate a point aren't defined"? They're just placeholders for scalar values - something like `xscale = 200`, `xoffset = 100` etc.

Comment: @Notlikethat Yes, sir, thanks you are right. I didn't put any value in . I am still new to matlab sometimes I miss things like that. I will put some value in and give it a try. thanks! and what do you mean spy(v) is the cheaty way? I never heard of that command.